# Host Git Code Over Internet

Tags: git

I have Git Repository created on my Server(location US). Now i need that some one who's location is in UK can access my repository and clone it in his PC. Is it Possible?

I can't have my static IP address and also not know about SSH setup?

Comment: Here's a start: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: Another: http://serverfault.com/questions/227804/why-cant-i-ssh-into-my-new-ec2-instance

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible, and there are a variety of different ways to do it.  In this answer, I've tried to describe your options whenever possible, as well as to offer my own recommendations based on my (limited) knowledge of your situation.

## Step 1: Serve your Git repository

You've got your Git repository on your server – great.  However, your contact in the UK can't clone off your server yet: when he or she tries to do so, his or her connection will be rejected, since your server doesn't know how to handle it.  You need to tell your server explicitly how to serve your Git repository.

How you do this depends somewhat on what you'd like to do later down the road.  If you'd like your UK friend to be able to push changes to the repository on the server, I recommend you set up your server as an SSH server and give your friend an account.  (There are alternative ways to enable read-write access, such as by using WebDAV; if you search around on the Web, you shouldn't have difficulty finding them.)  The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/) has good instructions on setting up your server as an SSH server, as well as on how to add a new user.

If, on the other hand, your UK contact only needs read access to the Git repository, you can use any Web server to serve your Git repository.  [*Pro Git*](http://git-scm.com/book/) has a good section on setting up Git to work with Apache, and you can find instructions elsewhere on the Web for other Web servers, such as lighttpd or nginx.  Note that you'll need to put your repository somewhere where your Web server will actually serve it – this is inside DocumentRoot for Apache, and somewhere similar for other servers.

Alternatively, you can set up Git's own server to serve repositories using the Git protocol.  *Pro Git* comes through here as well.

## Step 2: Open your firewall

Whether you're using SSH, a Web server, or the Git server, you'll need to open a port in your firewall to let in connections.  If nobody can connect to your server, nobody can read your repository.  If you're using SSH, you'll need to open TCP port 22; if a Web server, port 80; and if the Git server itself, port 9148.

If you're using iptables, you can run

> `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT --dport` *port_number*

where *port_number* is the port number you need to open.  Note that you'll need to be root – run `sudo -i` first if necessary.  Furthermore, this rule will probably reset itself when you reboot your server; look around on the Web to find how your GNU/Linux distribution handles persistent iptables rules.

If you're not using iptables, you'll need to search around on the Web, find some documentation for your firewall, and figure out how to open the relevant ports.

## Step 3: Find your server on the Internet

You mentioned you don't have a static IP address, and that's fine.  However, if you want Git to work properly, you'll need to be able to provide some kind of static identifier to your friend in the UK.  You should probably use a free dynamic DNS name, for which there are a whole host of options.  I've never used any of them myself, so I can't recommend any one in particular; perhaps other StackOverflow users have some advice.

## Step 4: Give your friend the clone URL

So you've got your repository on your server, you're all set up to serve it, you've got your firewall open, and you've got some kind of domain name for your server.  Now, you need your clone URL, the URL your UK contact will pass to git-clone to clone your repository.  This varies according to what choices you made in step 1 – if you've set up SSH, your clone URL is

> ssh://*friend's_username*@*your_server_domain_name*:*path_to_repository*

where *friend's_username* is the name on the user account you set up for your friend, *your_server_domain_name* is the domain name you got for your server in step 3, and *path_to_repository* is the actual Unix file system path to the shared repository.

If, on the other hand, you're using a Web server, your clone URL is an HTTP URL:

> http://*your_server_domain_name*/*repository*

where *repository* is the path to your repository, starting from your Web server's DocumentRoot.

If you're using the Git server, your clone URL starts with git://:

> git://*your_server_domain_name*/*repository_name*

where *repository_name* is the path to your repository, starting from the Git server's directory – often, /opt/git.

At this point, you're done.  Your friend should be able to use git-clone to clone your repository, and, if you've set up SSH access correctly, he or she should be able to push changes back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

1. use some online drive like google drive or dropbox to store the repository.
2. use some free ddns provider to get your domain name and set up the ssh server or http git service as Benjamin mentioned.